# Opening a dashboard link outside the component window

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

I am currently trying to simply put a link onto my dashboard. I am using a VF page with this simple code :

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://login.salesforce.com/">Main link!</apex:outputLink>
```

But it will only open the link up within the component's window. How do I force a link to open in full screen ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the link to open in the same window, add the target="_top" attribute to the link: 
apex:outputLink value="https://login.salesforce.com/" target="_top">Main link!

if you want to have it open in a new window/tab add target="_blank"
apex:outputLink value="https://login.salesforce.com/" target="_blank">Main link!